# how to avoid null values for newly added column tag in SQL?

Tags: mysql

How to avoid null values for newly added column tag in `SQL`?

[image]

Comment: Run a query to set them to the values you want

Comment: [`IFNULL(name_of_the_field, replacement_value)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

Comment: Or set a default value

Answer (score 0):

You can user IFNULL for replace NULL

```
IFNULL(COL1,'XYZ')
```

You can pass blank('') or any other Column value in Place of 'XYZ'

In your case Query will be:

```
 Select 
  IFNULL(name,'') as name, IFNULL(address,'') as address, IFNULL(rollno,'') as rollno, IFNULL(tag,'') as tag, IFNULL(section,'') as section
from details
```

It will not show Null in results

Answer (score -1):

if you have something to replace with NULL, You can Use

```
    ISNULL(COL1,'XYZ')
```

You can pass **blank('')** or any **other Column value** in Place of 'XYZ'

In your case *Query* will be:

```
    Select 
    ISNULL(name,'') ,ISNULL(address,'') ,ISNULL(rollno,'') ,ISNULL(tag,'')
    ,ISNULL(section,'') 
    from details
```

It will not show Null in results

Comment: `ISNULL()` returns a boolean and takes 1 parameter

Comment: ISNULL() function replaces NULL with a specified value

Comment: No. Please read [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull). The question is about MySQL, not SQL-Server